# Swift closure as AnyObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-runtime

Im trying to use this method: `class_addMethod()` which in Obj-c is used like this:

```
class_addMethod([self class], @selector(eventHandler), imp_implementationWithBlock(handler), "v@:");
```

And Im using it like this in Swift:

```
class_addMethod(NSClassFromString("UIBarButtonItem"), "handler", imp_implementationWithBlock(handler), "v@:")
```

It is an extension for `UIBarButtonItem` as you might have figured out.

`imp_implementationWithBlock` takes a parameter of type `AnyObject!`

How can I cast `()->()` into `AnyObject` ?

I've tried to cast it like this: `handler as AnyObject` but it gives me an error saying: `()->() does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'`

Comment: Did you try using `reinterpretCast()`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How can I cast `()->()` into `AnyObject` ?

**Warning**: This answer includes undocumented and unsafe feature in Swift. I doubt this passes AppStore review.

```
let f: ()->() = {
    println("test")
}

let imp = imp_implementationWithBlock(
    unsafeBitCast(
        f as @objc_block ()->(),
        AnyObject.self
    )
)
```

Comment: What is 'f' ? Is it the closure?

Comment: So why has Apple a `func imp_implementationWithBlock(_ block: AnyObject!) -> IMP` in the lib reference if you need that code you posted? Bug?

Comment: Obj-C code can passes Blocks to Swift `AnyObject` type parameter.

Comment: If you want to add this as an extension you are free to use it: `extension UIBarButtonItem {
    convenience init(title: String?, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle, handler: ()->()) {
        let imp = imp_implementationWithBlock(unsafeBitCast(handler as @objc_block ()->(), AnyObject.self))
        class_addMethod(UIBarButtonItem.self, "handler", imp, "v@:")
        self.init(title: title, style: style, target: nil, action: "handler")
        self.target = self
    }
}`

Comment: I'm not sure this extension does work as you expected. As far as I know, Method is class wide property, not instance local. So I think this results every instance shares same handler, no?

Comment: Hmm maybe the method will be created for every but only the ones I add the handler to will try to call it. But I will test it further.

Comment: Should use `@convention` instead of `@objc_block`

Answer (score 8):

You could write a wrapper, then pass it to the function

```
class ObjectWrapper<T> {
    let value :T
    init(value:T) {
       self.value = value
    }
}

let action = ObjectWarpper(value: {()->() in    
    // something
})
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 2, you should use `@convention` instead of `@objc_block`. See [Type Attribute](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH35-ID350)

```
func swizzle(type: AnyClass, original: Selector, methodType: MethodType, block: () -> Void) {
    let originalMethod = method(type, original: original, methodType: methodType)

    let castedBlock: AnyObject = unsafeBitCast(block as @convention(block) () -> Void, AnyObject.self)

    let swizzledImplementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(castedBlock)
    // More code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You can only cast it to `Any`.

- `AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type.
- `Any` can represent an instance of any type at all, including function types.

Apple Inc. „The Swift Programming Language.“ iBooks. https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l

Comment: But is there another way of doing this in any way?

Comment: Have you tried to pass `Selector("handler")`? Can you show the signature of `imp_implementationWithBlock `?

Comment: The error isnt the selector part, its the imp_implementationWithBlock() that is causing confuson

Comment: imp_implementationWithBlock(block: AnyObject!) takes only an AnyObject as parameter and returns an IMP

Comment: Its found in Objective-C Runtime references

Answer (score 2):

This has worked for me:

```
let myBlock: @objc_block () -> Void = { 
}
var mf : AnyObject = unsafeBitCast(myBlock, AnyObject.self)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 4.x (I think works in 3.x too), simply declaring the closure as `@convention(block)` should be enough to address compatibility thing:

```
// define the new implementation
let handler: @convention(block) (UIBarButtonItem) -> Void = { _ in }

// inject it into the class
class_addMethod(NSClassFromString("UIBarButtonItem"), sel_registerName("handler"), imp_implementationWithBlock(handler), "v@:")
```

Though, starting with Swift 3, `AnyObject` was converted to `Any` if the reference comes from Objective-C, so the code will compile even without the `@convention(block)` part, however it will crash at runtime as the compiler will not convert the Swift closure to an Objective-C block.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Any` object *(The protocol to which all types implicitly conform)*

```
 let aBlock: (view: View) -> Void = { view in /**/ }

 let block:Any? = aBlock
```