# Convert Swift 2 closure to Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c, swift2, closures, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to build an Objective-C block in Swift 2 in order to add it to an `NSArray` like so :

```
typealias CompletionBlock = () -> Void
let aBlock:CompletionBlock =  {
    print("Hello world!")
}
let nsArray = NSMutableArray()
nsArray.addObject(aBlock) // Error
```

I know it will work just fine with a Swift array, but I need an `NSArray` here for compatibility with existing Objective-C code. And if I use a swift array the compiler will refuse to cast it to an `NSArray` because it won't be a `[AnyObject]` (it will be a `[Any]`).

The problem here is that a swift closure is not an object contrary to Objective-C blocks which are objects behind the scene (they are instances of `NSBlock` which is a subclass of `NSObject`)

So my question is : How do a create an Objective-C block in swift ? I've tried using `@convention (block)` in the typealias but it doesn't work.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211973/swift-closure-as-anyobject or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586293/cast-closures-blocks ?

Comment: Thanks ! I missed that second answer with the proper use of `unsafeBitCast`. Sorry for the duplicate...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT :** As of Swift 3, this is completely unnecessary (and doesn't even work). Adding closures to Objective-C arrays works out of the box in Swift 3. The answer below is valid for Swift 2 only.

I know this is a duplicate but I will still post a refactored answer from [swift-closure-as-anyobject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211973/swift-closure-as-anyobject) and [cast-closures-blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586293/cast-closures-blocks) in case anyone lands on this one first.

The solution is to use the `unsafeBitCast` function to convert the Swift closure to an Objective-C compatible object before adding it to an `NSArray` and back before using it in Swift.

```
// The `@convention(block)` is important here in order to get
// Objective-C like memory management
typealias CompletionBlock = @convention(block) () -> Void

let aBlock:CompletionBlock = {
    print("Hello world!")
}
let nsArray = NSMutableArray()
let blockObject = unsafeBitCast(aBlock, AnyObject.self)
nsArray.addObject(blockObject)

let closureObject = nsArray[0]
let closure = unsafeBitCast(closureObject, CompletionBlock.self)
closure()
```